# STORAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED gridlock

Tags: limits, data-storage, rolluphelper

So I have a full copy sandbox that is at ~130 % data storage.  I can't seem to do anything without getting a **STORAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED** exception.

I've tried:

- Contacting support to see if they could temporarily increase the limit in the
  sandbox.  They told me to delete records.
- Tried deleting achieved tasks, but apparently rollup helper is attempting
  to insert a record on delete so this fails as well.
- Tried emptying the recycling bin, but it didn't free any space.

We're losing precious days on a tight timeline due to this issue.  Any ideas on how to get around this?

***PS: It's really important that the Sandbox is as close to Production as possible.***

Comment: Uninstall or disable rollup helper - Then delete records. That is the only way sans paying for a full sandbox (which it sounds like you need)

Comment: @Eric this IS in a full copy sandbox.  My clients production ORG is well over 100% data storage but I guess SF doesn't impose such strict limits in production as they do in sandbox.

Comment: You are correct. They are not as strict in production as it could impact the clients business.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable object truncation for custom objects and just truncate your largest objects. Thus bypasses triggers and so on. You may want back up whatever ia in the table first, if you care about the data.

Alternatively, just uninstall any offending packages that use too much space or that is causing failures, then perform your mad deletes.

Comment: unfortunately almost all the space was being used by standard objects.  Truncating would get me back below the threshold.  Uninstalling the package is an option, but I need to ensure that the org functions exactly as production for QA so I'm trying hard to avoid this.   I'm still hoping if I nag support hard enough they will increase the limit.

Comment: @NSjonas You can reinstall the package afterwards. Just remove it long enough to get below the threshold. Granted, I have heard that temporary increases are possible, but you'll only be granted a limited amount of time before you're reverted back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

What I have done is create a custom setting, Apex_Custom_Trigger_Status__c , that is a list of trigger names with one checkbox field named Active (true is default).

I have a class

```
global without sharing class ConfigUtil {
   public static Boolean isTriggerDeactivated(string name) {

     if (Test.isRunningTest())
       return false;

     Apex_Custom_Trigger_Status__c triggerSetting = Apex_Custom_Trigger_Status__c.getValues(name);
     if (triggerSetting != null){            
       return !triggerSetting.Active__c;
     }
     System.debug('### Trigger Custom Setting Name ' + triggerSetting.Name + ' Not Found - assume active');

     return false;
   }
}
```

Then in each trigger I added this code at top

```
if (ConfigUtil.isTriggerDeactivated('object_name_trigger_name')){
  return;
}
```

This enables me to temporarily disable triggers such as the rollup helper ones if I need to perform maintenance such as you describe.

Comment: Hey Maggie, looks like you posted this on the wrong question! If you copy and paste this onto the one it should be on I'll remove it from here :)